# Как разместить элементы в одну строку TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, tailwindcss

Пробовал flex, justify ии т.д. ничего не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items#basic-usage

Comment: вообще там работает поиск - отлично работает

Comment: а здесь: https://tailwindcss.ru/ ваще по русскому всё написано

Comment: https://tailwindcss.ru/docs/align-self/#center

Comment: Не работает, все превращается в кашу

Comment: покажите свой код а по картинкам гадают в тв предаче Гадалка